# why is my element only appending to one class?

Tags: javascript, css-selectors

I've been trying to dynamically append a div to inside multiple other divs:

```js
SoundCloudAPI.renderTracks = function createCards(){
    var card = document.createElement('div');
    card.classList.add("card");

    var searchResults = document.querySelector('.js-search-results');
    searchResults.appendChild(card);

    var imageDiv = document.createElement('div');
    imageDiv.classList.add("image");

    var imageResults = document.querySelector('.card');
    imageResults.appendChild(imageDiv);
}
```

however, it only appends to the first "card"
div in my body.

What's the problem here?

Comment: Nothing looks wrong with the logic, are you sure the `createCards()` function is being called correctly?

Comment: Also, you might want to post HTML code as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`querySelector` will return the first element with this class, so you have to use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) , then loop throught the found element using foreach to append you element as below

```
SoundCloudAPI.renderTracks = function createCards(){
    var card ;

    var searchResults = document.querySelectorAll('.js-search-results');
    // loop using foreach
    searchResults.forEach(function(searchResult) {
       card = document.createElement('div');
       card.classList.add("card");
       searchResult.appendChild(card);
    });

    var imageDiv;

    var imageResults = document.querySelectorAll('.card');
    // loop using foreach
    imageResults.forEach(function(imageResult) {
        imageDiv = document.createElement('div');
        imageDiv.classList.add("image");
        imageResult.appendChild(imageDiv);
    });

}
```

Comment: I don't think this will work, because you're only instantiating `card` **once**, and it will only ever refer to the very same node. Your `.forEach` will keep appending it to a new parent and removing it from the last one. You can circumvent this by doing this inside your `.forEach`: `imageResult.innerHTML = card.outerHTML`.

Comment: Also I think you meant to append `imageDiv` inside your last `.forEach()`, to which you'd have to do the same thing - use a mirror of its HTML to avoid reusing the same node over and over again.

Comment: @gyohza thanks for the comment , indeed you are right  , I corrected the answer as you mentioned ! thnx